# What is the emacs theme that is used on org-mode site?

Tags: org-mode, themes

What is the emacs theme that is used on org-mode site?

http://orgmode.org/img/main.jpg

Comment: idk, ask bastien :P

Comment: emacs -r ，i think

Comment: I am still investigating it. Any ideas?